# Discover which subdomains are getting DNS queries when wildcard is set

Tags: domain-name-system, wildcard

How can I see which subdomains are getting hits on DNS wildcard A record. I see lots of queries to *.example.com on a thrid-party DNS host but I can't get the statistics about the subdomains being accessed.

On the web server there are no visitors so it's not a option to check Apache's logs.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't see DNS query logs, you can't get reliable information about what values for the wildcard got queried. It might be that a client just resolved a name but didn't initiate any connection at all or only to a port your are not listening to or with a service that doesn't supply any host name information (e.g. SSH).

That said, if you only have Apache running and don't see any requests in your log files, it's very likely there were no DNS queries either.